# Google Drive API - Files List - What is `createdTime` vs `modifiedTime`?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am trying to list files that were created over the last 12 hours from a google drive using the google drive api. However, I've noticed that the `createdTime` appears to be *after* the `modifiedTime` in the files list response. Can someone explain to me what these two fields represent and how I can use one or the other to list files based on the datetime they were created?

Example response:

```json
{
  "createdTime": "2022-07-18T12:22:15.003Z",
  "id": "<FILE-ID>",
  "modifiedTime" : "2022-07-14T12:16:02.000Z",        // <-- earlier than createdTime
  "name": "<FILE-NAME>",
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To anyone else who runs into this issue:

It appears that the `modifiedTime` can be inherited from a file that is uploaded into the drive where as the `createdTime` is not and is, instead, the datetime the file was uploaded to the drive. Hence one can have a file that was "created" *after* it was "modified".

Also worth noting that I could not find this anywhere in the Google Drive API docs so it may be worth double checking.